# Is it common practice to use the same Namespace in multiple classes in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

I know what namespace is for but I'm not sure how the structure of a programs should be when using namespaces.

1- Do you use the same `namespace` name for all related classes in a program or do you use different namespace for each class?

2- If a unique namespace is more common, is it common to use the same name as the class?

Can some one give me some general advice on how `namespace` is used in `C#`?

**Example using the same namespace name:**

```
// Main program
using System;
using Zoo;

public class Program {
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dog buddy =  new Dog();
        buddy.bark();
        buddy.run();
    }
}

// Animal class
namespace Zoo{
    class Animal{
        public void run(){
            Console.WriteLine("Running...");
        }
    }
}

// Dog Class
namespace Zoo{
    class Dog:Animal{
        public void bark(){
            Console.WriteLine("Barking...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The point of namespaces is to group related classes together. Creating one namespace per class would be useless.

Comment: Make sense, I guess I was on the right track based on my example.

Comment: @ evelikov92. Thank you for the link, the second example from the top answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Microsoft's own guidelines regarding namespaces:

[Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx)

I hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason the link provided by @evelikov92 explains it better, second example from the top answers my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx) Is have some explaned. For what is used namespace in c#, and examples.

**UPDATE:** For your first question, I try to explain with some simple example. 
For example let's we have Library. This is like head namespace. In this Library you have books. And every book is some object. And this book is in namespace Library. So is possible to have only one namespace 'Library.BookName'. You can make every class in head namespace 'Library', But in common case in library books is separate in sections, like (sci-fi, sports etc.). And is better to have 'Library.Sport.BookName' like namespace.

And back in your question. You can use the same namespace for every class. But is better to separate in few namespaces, not to be in one namespace.

Comment: I update my answer and add some explanation for your first question. I hope is helps.

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as checked if it is good for you.